# Logging in with Facebook access_token to Facebook Javascript sdk without using facebook login popup

Tags: javascript, php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am using javascript sdk for login to facebook in my app. But actually i dont want to use facebook login popup else i wanted to use my site login screen where user is going to enter his fb credentials and after clicking on connect with fb he will login to fb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't possible! User must pass the facebook login (with that fb login popup), then only he can proceed. Check out for more details-

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/concepts/login/login-architecture/

FB.getLoginStatus can be used, but this will work only if the user is already logged-in with the facebook, and that's not always the case , so should be avoided.